# Как обрезать изображение в ImageView?

Tags: android, изображения, bitmap, imageview, android-customview

Использую ImageView с кругом. Нужно выводить ту часть изображения что в круге при каждом прикосновении. Примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код кастомного ImageView.

```
public class ImageWithCircleView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
private Paint mCirclePaint;
private int mCenterX =getBitmap().getWidth()/2 ;
private int mCenterY = getBitmap().getHeight() / 2;
private int mRadius = 50;


private BitmapCropListener bitmapCropListener = new BitmapCropListener() {
    @Override
    public void showImage(Bitmap bitmap) {

    }

    @Override
    public void hideImage() {

    }
};

public interface BitmapCropListener {

    void showImage(Bitmap bitmap);
    void hideImage();
}

public void setBitmapCropListener(BitmapCropListener bitmapCropListener) {
    this.bitmapCropListener = bitmapCropListener;
}



public ImageWithCircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}


private void init() {
    mCirclePaint = new Paint();
    mCirclePaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(4);

}

public void setRadius(int mRadius) {
    this.mRadius = mRadius;
    invalidate();
}


public int getRadius() {
    return mRadius;
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {


    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mCenterX = (int) event.getX();
            mCenterY = (int) event.getY();

            Log.i("Coo", mCenterX + " " + mCenterY);

            invalidate();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mCenterX = (int) event.getX();
            mCenterY= (int) event.getY();
           int x = mCenterX - mRadius;
            int y = mCenterY - mRadius;
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getBitmap(), x, y, 2 * mRadius, 2 * mRadius);
            bitmapCropListener.showImage(bitmap);
            Log.i("Coo", mCenterX + " " + mCenterY);
            invalidate();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            bitmapCropListener.hideImage();
            invalidate();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(mCenterX, mCenterY, mRadius, mCirclePaint);

}

private Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return ((BitmapDrawable) getDrawable()).getBitmap();
}
```

}

Comment: Советую посмотреть этот вопрос. Он о том, как обрезать изображение кругом:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932805/cropping-circular-area-from-bitmap-in-android А как кадрировать для этого изображения, как вижу, вы уже разобрались.

Comment: Меня больше  интересует как превратить координаты точки ImageView в координаты Bitmap.

Comment: Вот нахождение точки прикосновения относительно изображения. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038867/android-how-to-detect-touch-location-on-imageview-if-the-image-view-is-scaled-b